# how to make js code reusable for different image sliders

Tags: javascript, html, dom, javascript-objects

I am learning JS, and I did an image slider that works but I want that when the big image is clicked, it opens the same image slider but bigger and more focused on the images

this is the code for the image slider I have that works:

```html
<div class="product-imgs">
            <div class="img-display">
              <button class="hero__button hero__button--max-desktop hero__button--left left-arrow" id="left">
                <svg width="12" height="18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="left">
                  <path d="M11 1 3 9l8 8" stroke="#1D2026" stroke-width="3" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" id="left" />
                </svg>
              </button>

              <div class="img-showcase">
                <img class="carousel__image product-img" src="./images/image-product-1.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="carousel__image product-img" src="./images/image-product-2.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="carousel__image product-img" src="./images/image-product-3.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="carousel__image product-img" src="./images/image-product-4.jpg" alt="">
              </div>

              <button class="hero__button hero__button--max-desktop hero__button--right right-arrow" id="right">
                <svg width="13" height="18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="right">
                  <path d="m2 1 8 8-8 8" stroke="#1D2026" stroke-width="3" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" id="right" />
                </svg>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="img-select">
              <div class="img-item">
                <a href="#" data-id="1">
                  <img class="product-img" src="./images/image-product-1.jpg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="img-item">
                <a href="#" data-id="2">
                  <img class="product-img" src="./images/image-product-2.jpg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="img-item">
                <a href="#" data-id="3">
                  <img class="product-img" src="./images/image-product-3.jpg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="img-item">
                <a href="#" data-id="4">
                  <img class="product-img" src="./images/image-product-4.jpg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".img-select a");
const imgBtns = [...imgs];
let imgId = 1;

imgBtns.forEach((imgItem) => {
  imgItem.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (imgId !== imgItem.dataset.id) {
      document
        .querySelector(`a[data-id="${imgId}"]`)
        .parentNode.classList.remove("selected");
      document.querySelector(`a[data-id="${imgId}"]`).style.opacity = 1;
      imgItem.parentNode.classList.add("selected");
      imgItem.style.opacity = 0.5;
    }

    imgId = imgItem.dataset.id;
    slideImage();
  });
});

function slideImage() {
  const displayWidth = document.querySelector(
    ".img-showcase img:first-child"
  ).clientWidth;

  document.querySelector(".img-showcase").style.transform = `translateX(${
    -(imgId - 1) * displayWidth
  }px)`;
}
```

my idea is to have another "Card" of html with the same html code, and make it visible when the big image is clicked, but then because there would be 2 cards the same JavaScript code would not work, because of this, so it takes the first image width of the first image slider and when I try to move the bigger image slider it breaks because the images in the second image slider are bigger:

```js
function slideImage() {
  const displayWidth = document.querySelector(
    ".img-showcase img:first-child"
  ).clientWidth;
```

I tried to make the JS work for both image slider and change this part of the code, so I used .querySelectorAll and the forEach, and it works, but the images break because of the variable displayWidth is taking the first image slider width and the second image slider is bigger:

```js
function slideImage() {
  const displayWidth = document.querySelector(
    ".img-showcase img:first-child"
  ).clientWidth;


  document.querySelectorAll(".img-showcase").forEach(el => el.style.transform = `translateX(${
    -(imgId - 1) * displayWidth
  }px)`)
}
```

s